# Delta files, delta tables and delta transactions

Tags: hive, databricks, delta-lake, data-lakehouse

I have a serious issue understanding Delta tables, delta transaction logs, and delta Files.

Questions:

- What and where are the delta tables. I don't understand if they are in the metastore(hive), in object-store (s3) or in both.
- What and where are the delta files. Same situation, I don't understand what is considered delta file. I can see parquet files both in Hive (multiple) and a single one in the /tmp folder.

This is what I resumed from reading the information.

- Delta tables

  - Contain underlying file location path
  - Table properties
  - Table Schema definition
  - kept in a metastore (i.e. Apache Hive)
- Delta transaction logs

  - Stores every executed transaction.
  - Single source of truth for delta table changes
  - Enable ACID properties and thus, time-traveling
    and versioning
- Delta Files

  - Transaction Log files
  - Atomic units - commits
  - Stored in Cloud object Storage (AWS, MS Azure, GCP) or a file system (HDFS)
  - Plain data files (Apache Parquet / OCR) or partition folders (Year-Month-Day)
- Delta engine (paid)

  - Performance optimization for SQL and DataFrames

I'm not sure how to understand this..

Comment: The question is about Delta Lake, not Hive

Comment: Yes, in the example I was checking they use Hive for the metastore.

Comment: @leftjoin the question is about both imo.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I follow Databricks/Delta.io terminology here but either way it may help your understanding. The metadata in Delta Lake is part of the data. So a delta table would be the data files (parquet) plus the metadata (DeltaLog = _delta_log directory within a Delta table). So a delta table directory usually looks sth like below (of any file example here, there can be many files; also we ignore some details like checkpoint files):

- tablename/

  - part-*.snappy.parquet
  - _delta_log/*.crc
  - _delta_log/*.json

This is different to a parquet table which does not hold all this metadata. Irrespective of the table format (e.g. delta or parquet) you register the table in Hive. Hive will hold some metadata. Given that a delta table already holds a lot of metadata, the Hive metadata stored for it will differ from what is stored for a parquet table (or any other format). All these things are probably best explained with an example. I will use (Azure) Databricks as an engine since all is set up in the runtime already but it should equally apply to OSS Spark + Delta + Hive. Azure data lake is the storage and access protocol is abfss.

**Create db in spark sql**

```
create database if not exists test_ext location 'abfss://mycontainer@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/test'
```

On Hive DB

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DBS]
```

| DB_ID | DESC | DB_LOCATION_URI | NAME | OWNER_NAME | OWNER_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 |  | abfss://mycontainer@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/test | test_ext | root | USER |

**Create tables in spark sql and insert data**

We use the classic diamonds dataset which is baked into Databricks datasets but can also be found on public sources, e.g. [GitHub/tidyverse/ggplot2/diamonds](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/data-raw/diamonds.csv).
We create two tables, one delta and one parquet format.

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv')
df.write.format("delta").partitionBy("cut").saveAsTable("test_ext.diamonds_partitioned")
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("cut").saveAsTable("test_ext.diamonds_partitioned_parquet")
```

**File system**

First we look at what happened on file system level. The database is a directory here:

`storage_acoount/mycontainer/test`

The tables can be found within:

`storage_acoount/mycontainer/test/diamonds_partitioned`
`storage_acoount/mycontainer/test/diamonds_partitioned_parquet`

Now on table level, we see (note that data files are in subdirectories due to the partitioning by column `cut`):

- storage_acoount/mycontainer/test/diamonds_partitioned

  - _delta_log

    - 000*.crc
    - 000*.json
  - cut=Fair

    - part-000*.parquet
  - ...
- storage_acoount/mycontainer/test/diamonds_partitioned_parquet

  - cut=Fair

    - part-000*.parquet
  - ...
  - _SUCCESS

**Hive metadata**

Now we can look at different metadata such as columns, partitions, table parameters, etc.

On Hive DB

```
select * from dbo.[TBLS]
```

| TBL_ID | CREATE_TIME | DB_ID | LAST_ACCESS_TIME | OWNER | RETENTION | SD_ID | TBL_NAME | TBL_TYPE | VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT | VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT | IS_REWRITE_ENABLED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 1659599317 | 11 | 0 | root | 0 | 32 | diamonds_partitioned | MANAGED_TABLE | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 33 | 1659599932 | 11 | 0 | root | 0 | 33 | diamonds_partitioned_parquet | MANAGED_TABLE | NULL | NULL | 0 |

The table parameters already show us some differences. For example, there is no partition information for the delta table. However, we will find it in the _delta_log files as the metadata is stored together with the data. On the other hand, delta brings metadata which parquet does not have.

```
select * from dbo.[TABLE_PARAMS]
```

| TBL_ID | PARAM_KEY | PARAM_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | delta.lastCommitTimestamp | 1659599315000 |
| 32 | delta.lastUpdateVersion | 0 |
| 32 | delta.minReaderVersion | 1 |
| 32 | delta.minWriterVersion | 2 |
| 32 | spark.sql.create.version | 3.2.1 |
| 32 | spark.sql.partitionProvider | catalog |
| 32 | spark.sql.sources.provider | delta |
| 32 | spark.sql.sources.schema | {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"_c0","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"carat","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"cut","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"color","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"clarity","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"depth","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"table","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"price","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"x","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"y","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"z","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]} |
| 32 | transient_lastDdlTime | 1659599317 |
| 33 | spark.sql.create.version | 3.2.1 |
| 33 | spark.sql.partitionProvider | catalog |
| 33 | spark.sql.sources.provider | parquet |
| 33 | spark.sql.sources.schema | {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"_c0","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"carat","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"color","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"clarity","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"depth","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"table","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"price","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"x","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"y","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"z","type":"double","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"cut","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]} |
| 33 | spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols | 1 |
| 33 | spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0 | cut |
| 33 | transient_lastDdlTime | 1659599933 |

When we look at column info, we realize that delta only stores a generic `array<string>` while parquet stores metadata for all columns.

```
select * from dbo.[COLUMNS_V2]
```

| CD_ID | COMMENT | COLUMN_NAME | TYPE_NAME | INTEGER_IDX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | from deserializer | col | `array<string>` | 0 |
| 33 | NULL | _c0 | int | 0 |
| 33 | NULL | carat | double | 1 |
| 33 | NULL | clarity | string | 3 |
| 33 | NULL | color | string | 2 |
| 33 | NULL | depth | double | 4 |
| 33 | NULL | price | int | 6 |
| 33 | NULL | table | double | 5 |
| 33 | NULL | x | double | 7 |
| 33 | NULL | y | double | 8 |
| 33 | NULL | z | double | 9 |

**DeltaLog metadata**

Finally, we can look at different metadata in the delta log. As you can see there is a lot of table and column metadata but also data statistics.

First `0000*.json`.

```
[
  {
    "protocol": {
      "minReaderVersion": 1,
      "minWriterVersion": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "metaData": {
      "id": "ef7ac39f-0977-4992-a087-a6a9f49fe650",
      "format": {
        "provider": "parquet",
        "options": {}
      },
      "schemaString": "{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"_c0\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"carat\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"cut\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"color\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"clarity\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"depth\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"table\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"price\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"x\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"y\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"z\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}",
      "partitionColumns": [
        "cut"
      ],
      "configuration": {},
      "createdTime": 1659599309716
    }
  },
  {
    "add": {
      "path": "cut=Fair/part-00000-fc4c091e-4b55-434c-92f6-6e87a18f6c76.c000.snappy.parquet",
      "partitionValues": {
        "cut": "Fair"
      },
      "size": 32547,
      "modificationTime": 1659599313000,
      "dataChange": true,
      "stats": "{\"numRecords\":1610,\"minValues\":{\"_c0\":9,\"carat\":0.22,\"color\":\"D\",\"clarity\":\"I1\",\"depth\":43.0,\"table\":49.0,\"price\":337,\"x\":0.0,\"y\":0.0,\"z\":0.0},\"maxValues\":{\"_c0\":53883,\"carat\":5.01,\"color\":\"J\",\"clarity\":\"VVS2\",\"depth\":79.0,\"table\":95.0,\"price\":18574,\"x\":10.74,\"y\":10.54,\"z\":6.98},\"nullCount\":{\"_c0\":0,\"carat\":0,\"color\":0,\"clarity\":0,\"depth\":0,\"table\":0,\"price\":0,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}}",
      "tags": {
        "INSERTION_TIME": "1659599313000000",
        "OPTIMIZE_TARGET_SIZE": "268435456"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "add": {
      "path": "cut=Good/part-00000-4ed7e5c8-7a6c-49a4-a2a8-9fdb2d81ead2.c000.snappy.parquet",
      "partitionValues": {
        "cut": "Good"
      },
      "size": 76488,
      "modificationTime": 1659599313000,
      "dataChange": true,
      "stats": "{\"numRecords\":4906,\"minValues\":{\"_c0\":3,\"carat\":0.23,\"color\":\"D\",\"clarity\":\"I1\",\"depth\":54.3,\"table\":51.0,\"price\":327,\"x\":0.0,\"y\":0.0,\"z\":0.0},\"maxValues\":{\"_c0\":53937,\"carat\":3.01,\"color\":\"J\",\"clarity\":\"VVS2\",\"depth\":67.0,\"table\":66.0,\"price\":18788,\"x\":9.44,\"y\":9.38,\"z\":5.79},\"nullCount\":{\"_c0\":0,\"carat\":0,\"color\":0,\"clarity\":0,\"depth\":0,\"table\":0,\"price\":0,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}}",
      "tags": {
        "INSERTION_TIME": "1659599313000001",
        "OPTIMIZE_TARGET_SIZE": "268435456"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "add": {
      "path": "cut=Ideal/part-00000-67ceda5d-c6c0-477f-8b27-0b1ba9688764.c000.snappy.parquet",
      "partitionValues": {
        "cut": "Ideal"
      },
      "size": 292297,
      "modificationTime": 1659599314000,
      "dataChange": true,
      "stats": "{\"numRecords\":21551,\"minValues\":{\"_c0\":1,\"carat\":0.2,\"color\":\"D\",\"clarity\":\"I1\",\"depth\":43.0,\"table\":43.0,\"price\":326,\"x\":0.0,\"y\":0.0,\"z\":0.0},\"maxValues\":{\"_c0\":53940,\"carat\":3.5,\"color\":\"J\",\"clarity\":\"VVS2\",\"depth\":66.7,\"table\":63.0,\"price\":18806,\"x\":9.65,\"y\":31.8,\"z\":6.03},\"nullCount\":{\"_c0\":0,\"carat\":0,\"color\":0,\"clarity\":0,\"depth\":0,\"table\":0,\"price\":0,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}}",
      "tags": {
        "INSERTION_TIME": "1659599313000002",
        "OPTIMIZE_TARGET_SIZE": "268435456"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "add": {
      "path": "cut=Premium/part-00000-8c05dee7-a5ce-4f29-a8b1-7bbc403f391d.c000.snappy.parquet",
      "partitionValues": {
        "cut": "Premium"
      },
      "size": 199912,
      "modificationTime": 1659599314000,
      "dataChange": true,
      "stats": "{\"numRecords\":13791,\"minValues\":{\"_c0\":2,\"carat\":0.2,\"color\":\"D\",\"clarity\":\"I1\",\"depth\":58.0,\"table\":51.0,\"price\":326,\"x\":0.0,\"y\":0.0,\"z\":0.0},\"maxValues\":{\"_c0\":53939,\"carat\":4.01,\"color\":\"J\",\"clarity\":\"VVS2\",\"depth\":63.0,\"table\":62.0,\"price\":18823,\"x\":10.14,\"y\":58.9,\"z\":8.06},\"nullCount\":{\"_c0\":0,\"carat\":0,\"color\":0,\"clarity\":0,\"depth\":0,\"table\":0,\"price\":0,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}}",
      "tags": {
        "INSERTION_TIME": "1659599313000003",
        "OPTIMIZE_TARGET_SIZE": "268435456"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "add": {
      "path": "cut=Very%20Good/part-00000-9a3e66de-4c74-4f30-af25-95fa2625e3a6.c000.snappy.parquet",
      "partitionValues": {
        "cut": "Very Good"
      },
      "size": 182719,
      "modificationTime": 1659599314000,
      "dataChange": true,
      "stats": "{\"numRecords\":12082,\"minValues\":{\"_c0\":6,\"carat\":0.2,\"color\":\"D\",\"clarity\":\"I1\",\"depth\":56.8,\"table\":44.0,\"price\":336,\"x\":0.0,\"y\":0.0,\"z\":0.0},\"maxValues\":{\"_c0\":53938,\"carat\":4.0,\"color\":\"J\",\"clarity\":\"VVS2\",\"depth\":64.9,\"table\":66.0,\"price\":18818,\"x\":10.01,\"y\":9.94,\"z\":31.8},\"nullCount\":{\"_c0\":0,\"carat\":0,\"color\":0,\"clarity\":0,\"depth\":0,\"table\":0,\"price\":0,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}}",
      "tags": {
        "INSERTION_TIME": "1659599313000004",
        "OPTIMIZE_TARGET_SIZE": "268435456"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "commitInfo": {
      "timestamp": 1659599315007,
      "userId": "1234567891234567",
      "userName": "user@org.com",
      "operation": "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT",
      "operationParameters": {
        "isManaged": "true",
        "description": null,
        "partitionBy": "[\"cut\"]",
        "properties": "{}"
      },
      "notebook": {
        "notebookId": "1234567891234567"
      },
      "clusterId": "1234-123456-abcdefghi",
      "isolationLevel": "WriteSerializable",
      "isBlindAppend": true,
      "operationMetrics": {
        "numFiles": "5",
        "numOutputRows": "53940",
        "numOutputBytes": "783963"
      },
      "engineInfo": "Databricks-Runtime/10.4.x-scala2.12",
      "txnId": "123abc-123abc-123abc-123abc-123abc"
    }
  }
]
```

And then `000*.crc`.

```
{
  "tableSizeBytes": 783963,
  "numFiles": 5,
  "numMetadata": 1,
  "numProtocol": 1,
  "protocol": {
    "minReaderVersion": 1,
    "minWriterVersion": 2
  },
  "metadata": {
    "id": "ef7ac39f-0977-4992-a087-a6a9f49fe650",
    "format": {
      "provider": "parquet",
      "options": {}
    },
    "schemaString": "{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"_c0\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"carat\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"cut\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"color\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"clarity\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"depth\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"table\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"price\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"x\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"y\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"z\",\"type\":\"double\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}",
    "partitionColumns": [
      "cut"
    ],
    "configuration": {},
    "createdTime": 1659599309716
  },
  "histogramOpt": {
    "sortedBinBoundaries": [
      0,
      8192,
      16384,
      32768,
      65536,
      ...
    ],
    "fileCounts": [
      0,
      0,
      1,
      0,
      1,
      ...
    ],
    "totalBytes": [
      0,
      0,
      32547,
      0,
      76488,
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

A few interesting resources around the topic

- [Databricks Blog: Diving Into Delta Lake: Unpacking The Transaction Log](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/08/21/diving-into-delta-lake-unpacking-the-transaction-log.html)
- [lakeFS Blog: Hive Metastore – It Didn’t Age Well](https://lakefs.io/hive-metastore-it-didnt-age-well/)
- [Yishuang Lu on Medium: Migrating from Hive to Delta Lake + Hive in Hybrid Cloud Environment](https://medium.com/amobee-engineering/migrating-from-hive-to-delta-lake-hive-in-hybrid-cloud-environment-38269ed45632)

**ADDITION:**

A small addition as to the file format differences in Hive metadata that I recently stumbled upon and found a bit surprising. When adding comments to a table via table properties, they are directly stored under the table ID in Hive `dbo.table_params` in `PARAM_KEY` = `comment` (assuming you follow Hive standards for comments) for file formats like `csv` or `parquet` but they do not show up in Hive for `delta` tables. For `delta` tables we only find the comment in respective `_delta_log`. I find this a bit surprising as comments are official table properties in [Hive LanguageManual DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL). In this case I would have expected to find the comment in the delta log as well as in Hive but probably the Delta metadata implementation has consciously decided against it. But then why have other metadata like `spark.sql.sources.schema` twice? It's not perfectly clear to me.

You can easily test this as shown below.

```
create table if not exists test.test_csv (myint int) using CSV;
create table if not exists test.test_parquet (myint int) using parquet;
create table if not exists test.test_delta (myint int) using delta;

alter table test.test_csv SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = 'A table comment');
alter table test.test_parquet SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = 'A table comment');
alter table test.test_delta SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = 'A table comment');

--In Hive:

create or alter view dbo.v_tables as
SELECT 
    TBLS.TBL_ID
    ,DBS.NAME as DB_NAME
    ,TBLS.TBL_NAME
    ,TBLS.TBL_TYPE
FROM TBLS
    ,DBS
WHERE TBLS.DB_ID = DBS.DB_ID

select * from dbo.v_tables tbls left join dbo.table_params params on tbls.TBL_ID = params.TBL_ID
where tbls.db_name = 'test' and tbls.tbl_name = 'test_csv'

...
```